# Admob ads freezes my iOS game (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, iphone, admob, sprite-kit

I use Apple’s SpriteKit in my iOS game and I use admob ads.
When admob is loading new ad my game is freezing. How to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: when you call the loading of banners? at what point of the scene?

Comment: @Ilario I work with admob in ViewController. I create banners and call loadRequest method in viewDidLoad. I put ad banners on SKView. The problem is my app freezes for 1-3 second when ad is changing.

Comment: you should call loadRequest after that the scene is loading..

Comment: @Ilario  Thanks! But it doesn't work for me. AdMod blocks main thread of game.

Answer (score 1):

I also use admob in my app, I also noticed that when the banner appears there is a freeze of the scene for about one second..

but in my case I think it happened because I was the request of the banner while the scene was loading textures, so i solved moving the loadRequest after the load of textures.

in my `initWithSize`: i call a method that load the textures, at the end of this method i do:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showBanner) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
```

In this way I was able to avoid the problems involved in loading the banner, and so the scene does not freeze more,

try and let me know

Comment: Thanks again! App has lags if I add new nodes on scene after adding ad banner. Is that true or not?

Comment: yes for me it is true.. still having the same problem?

Comment: Yes, I have this problem because I'm adding new nodes on scene. Today I'll rewrite my code.